# How do to determine axis angle from rotation matrix using Eigen Libary

Tags: c++, matrix, rotation, transformation, eigen

The Eigen Library supports creating a matrix with axis-angle arguments. How do you perform the opposite and determine the axis-angle from a matrix (I'm not interested in the Euler set, just a single axis-angle result).

Answer (score 10):

Eigen supplies an [`AngleAxis`](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1AngleAxis.html) constructor that takes a matrix as an argument. So, it is simply:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Core>
#include <Eigen/Geometry>


int main()
{
    Eigen::Vector3d axis;
    axis.setRandom();
    std::cout << axis << "\n\n";
    axis.normalize();
    std::cout << axis << "\n\n";

    Eigen::Matrix3d mat;
    mat = Eigen::AngleAxisd(0.256, axis);

    Eigen::AngleAxisd newAngleAxis(mat);

    std::cout << newAngleAxis.angle() << "\n" << newAngleAxis.axis() << "\n\n";

    return 0;

}
```

Which outputs:

> -0.997497
>    0.127171
>   -0.613392
>
> -0.846852
>    0.107965
>   -0.520755
>
> 0.256
>   -0.846852
>    0.107965
>   -0.520755

or something similar.